# I want to trigger a View in Eclipse RCP through the handler also want to pass source object which have invoked the command

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have added a command (push button) in my plugin project.
Now in the handler I want whenever that command is initiated a new view will open.
But the thing is I also want to pass some input to view from my handler.
Please suggest with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a 3.x compatibility mode plugin you show the view using:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart viewPart = page.showView("view id");
```

where "view id" is the id of the view you declared in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point.

The view part returned is an instance of your view class so you can call a method on the view to pass in your data:

```java
MyView myView = (myView)viewPart;

myView.setParameters(your parameters);
```

where `MyView` is your view class and `setParameters` is a method that you write.